# How to not include delimiters in actionscript 3 split

Tags: string, actionscript-3

I know this seems like a stupid question, since the default behavior is to not include the delimiters. However, it is including it in my case and I have no idea why. I have a text file of words separated by newlines, like so:

```
word
other
language
name
etc
```

I put the whole text file into a string, then try to split it into an array using the String.split method, which works fine. At the end, I have an array of words. However, odd behavior with the strings down the road made me realize that the strings are including the delimiter. Each word is one length longer than it should be, and that extra character is at the end and is the newline character.

This is my code

```
wordArray = dictionary.split("\n");
```

Is there any reason why this would include the newline character in the word?

Answer (score 1):

Try broadening the collection of characters that it will split at, e.g.

```
wordArray = str.split(/[\s\n]+/g);
```

This will split at one or more whitespace or newline characters.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Why? I get that you're telling it to split on any whitespace or newline, but what is /g?

Comment: Also, I'd love to know why exactly it is deciding to keep the newline character when I was splitting before even though \n was the delimiter

Comment: @JoshuaZollinger `g` is a modifier that tells the pattern to split at more than one instance. It's hard to say without the text file you're reading from in my hands, it could be anything really (even characters that don't render in most text editors but act as a newline etc).